# Prevent from inserting char, and firing new event

Tags: javascript, events, input, focus

I have problem with, capturing "keydown" and then change focus to "last active" focus.

If I set focus to particular element within function that captures event,   "input" element  get a "char" afterwards , or whole "form" element capture "enter" to submit form again.

My code:

http://jsfiddle.net/BluesM/KkexX/4/

I found way but this is clunky. Within function that capture event I do

```
 setTimeout(function(){newFocus.focus();  }, 30);
```

where

```
newFocus
```

Is the element which I want set focus on.

But maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `preventDefault()` on keydown after form is submited.

http://jsfiddle.net/KkexX/7/

Comment: Thank you very much! But why if I set the e.preventDefault() within "dismiss" function it won't work.

Why you have to run it after "dismiss" executed not within ?

Comment: Because in dismiss function you don't have access to the event 'e' from keydown. You either place prevenDefault() in the keydown, or you can pass the event as an argument to the dismiss function and prevenDefault() there.